# Akka cluster singleton not found

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-cluster

I am trying to create a Singleton actor and I found the documentation on [Akka Cluster Singletons](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-singleton.html). The issue I am facing is that whenever I try to send a message to my singleton, it is not found by the `ClusterSingletonProxy` actor. I enabled debug logs and when I send a message to the proxy this appears from the `/user/consumerProxy` actor.

> Singleton not available, buffering message type [java.lang.String]

This is how I set up my singleton.

```
object FetchStatusActor {
  def props() = {
    println(" PROPS CALLED ")

    Props(new FetchStatusActor())
  }
}

class FetchStatusActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg => println(s" Fetch actor got: ${msg}")
  }
}

val manager = system.actorOf(
   ClusterSingletonManager.props(
      singletonProps = FetchStatusActor.props(),
      terminationMessage = "some-termination-msg",
      settings = ClusterSingletonManagerSettings(system)
   ),
   name = "consumer"
 )
    
 val proxy = system.actorOf(
    ClusterSingletonProxy.props(
       singletonManagerPath = "/user/consumer",
       settings = ClusterSingletonProxySettings(system)
    ),
    name = "consumerProxy"
 )

 proxy ! "Say something"
```

The println from `FetchStatusActor.props` appears.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't seem to have any effect. I also tried `Props(classOf[FetchStatusActor])`. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: Shooting in the dark a bit here, but can you check you have akka.actor.provide=cluster? I think singleton requires that and it's not obvious from your question if you have that setup correctly and you actually run in clutster mode (and not in local mode). Check out documentation on cluster

Comment: Yes, I did set `akka.actor.provider = "cluster"`. I found out about it because play was throwing an error about this.

Comment: This code works for me on 2.6.13 with the following configuration akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
  remote.artery {
    canonical {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2551
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

    downing-provider-class = "akka.cluster.sbr.SplitBrainResolverProvider"
  }
}

Comment: Thanks for checking. I think the Play framework requires some extra configuration. I got to this [documentation link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AkkaIntegrations) that seems related. I decided not to use a singleton actor after all. I can do what I want with scheduled async tasks.